# Deserialize PHP JSON to C Sharp datagridview

Tags: c#, php, json, datagridview

Can anyone help me with my deserialisation of my JSON. I tried json2csharp, i got the class but when I try it, it keeps coming up empty and shows an error.

JSON:

```
{"data":[{"officeID":"L4UFJw8GpQPg8iryJlHgeQ8L9wvGaGMozF33HxYrouY=","firstName":"R6UELs10\/qC+e9Iej1Sfh44H53bC1iez1FX9UoBdmL4=","lastName":"dZh5xGkYre\/Qjv\/d8PnYE+0F+YB\/pACDsOhnbT1vC7I=","userName":"oJ9SUemStHW6XGJrRSgQJxBUxHIWKejj3yVjbxiNHH8=","birthdate":"386TvajxJiPRXU4UT5OIqH3jmgSqqmv+n09tqxR9458=","email":"1kuUiACYGwkHseT32NfCbb6QH68Mq09ur5LdBo2SzUhdD6mWQjN9leekZrcZVmzcVCfSA4iEgTIspS3j8naYjg==","functionCategoryID":"79kSmrt7HmEYhqBd+NGd8la3NRVkSaeU+9rx7ri\/jG0="},{"officeID":"Ue86sZNLpM0dZXDBbAw4bgpg36te\/Uym3j\/7c\/RK6So=","firstName":"OK6EiNwnB7Ixb25ua62Us1sCMQ3VlGrjAawtU5pamFk=","lastName":"OK6EiNwnB7Ixb25ua62Us1sCMQ3VlGrjAawtU5pamFk=","userName":"OK6EiNwnB7Ixb25ua62Us1sCMQ3VlGrjAawtU5pamFk=","birthdate":"CgQqdhV3+ZnCSwN6+o9b0kP8i107pgERzWYolkp6dWA=","email":"GHm0Re5AMOEXVjmeuscd5JUAswdDQsvqxzzolEXZ75g=","functionCategoryID":"uIPaVTdcTsORfPMM9kjOdoB5Mf5bZShp2eDrt0bhJA8="},{"officeID":"TQ8MQHfCxpu4XMAYJpDcJ9JIGJ\/oZdZTwirC3O9RoRQ=","firstName":"8PIIK6lsX4q9l39oS+ZIlkpKyhnisTVI3d2qa9Rk7IU=","lastName":"8PIIK6lsX4q9l39oS+ZIlkpKyhnisTVI3d2qa9Rk7IU=","userName":"8PIIK6lsX4q9l39oS+ZIlkpKyhnisTVI3d2qa9Rk7IU=","birthdate":"CgQqdhV3+ZnCSwN6+o9b0kP8i107pgERzWYolkp6dWA=","email":"5EID57UhzVapKSu0hPdlU8++ScgjslS5qiqkNGk5Urk=","functionCategoryID":"uIPaVTdcTsORfPMM9kjOdoB5Mf5bZShp2eDrt0bhJA8="},{"officeID":"87Qn9VDRcho3E9SpkkmN3Voow4xbVRrP6Eg1e9q+LTk=","firstName":"j3PjfbjwOyP\/s2kiXWUrFQT33985hJhymjSgyvVWD88=","lastName":"j3PjfbjwOyP\/s2kiXWUrFQT33985hJhymjSgyvVWD88=","userName":"j3PjfbjwOyP\/s2kiXWUrFQT33985hJhymjSgyvVWD88=","birthdate":"aAYSiKoBVvMZ\/x7zZ3fKW8SLDxSNzSguQ2VtpFqn1\/g=","email":"cnHQfIfyGbaSGW9aVPCPkpZ0fxtN2vH8\/Rmhfa61GpU=","functionCategoryID":"uIPaVTdcTsORfPMM9kjOdoB5Mf5bZShp2eDrt0bhJA8="},{"officeID":"fJrhmHvZkTb909xEuy9GBDFTzwmBqOAzJMSdv\/z2NeY=","firstName":"R6UELs10\/qC+e9Iej1Sfh44H53bC1iez1FX9UoBdmL4=","lastName":"dZh5xGkYre\/Qjv\/d8PnYE+0F+YB\/pACDsOhnbT1vC7I=","userName":"u2Q+5N0qfGXguAAXPrjfg27bKcsfn9kmuFirw3D+ESE=","birthdate":"aAYSiKoBVvMZ\/x7zZ3fKW8SLDxSNzSguQ2VtpFqn1\/g=","email":"acpGLJU7viDD8bvDP6cehUtKu4jsu0S7NocWzWI5HsU=","functionCategoryID":"uIPaVTdcTsORfPMM9kjOdoB5Mf5bZShp2eDrt0bhJA8="},{"officeID":"+F8IDemrdYxhfhZRffkcfpC8XRS13jl1zee8jCYZo+k=","firstName":"R6UELs10\/qC+e9Iej1Sfh44H53bC1iez1FX9UoBdmL4=","lastName":"dZh5xGkYre\/Qjv\/d8PnYE+0F+YB\/pACDsOhnbT1vC7I=","userName":"ZaBSv\/5EzxsxaPLVex1m3s0FZ5AAsPHejn1N7qe5lHo=","birthdate":"aAYSiKoBVvMZ\/x7zZ3fKW8SLDxSNzSguQ2VtpFqn1\/g=","email":"dluwI6UQb8M\/eRyaw0YHfX2+kfK2Q1HebrBoQP9Uths=","functionCategoryID":"LwtYJQvWw97ejLbYWRFJn+S5sVKVXvzDXgYat4Le5zQ="},{"officeID":"7jqdChVFIQt5cdXznM5Qmv1EOqgfpi580OHek1L2FVA=","firstName":"R6UELs10\/qC+e9Iej1Sfh44H53bC1iez1FX9UoBdmL4=","lastName":"dZh5xGkYre\/Qjv\/d8PnYE+0F+YB\/pACDsOhnbT1vC7I=","userName":"iShpHaczQ4RtkHVvXmv3nRv8m59qppApLQ99Civ1QlU=","birthdate":"aAYSiKoBVvMZ\/x7zZ3fKW8SLDxSNzSguQ2VtpFqn1\/g=","email":"pq9yUcG+VK5xlHpemKm9B7sE7PxlCdCkFpzhIy\/8k8g=","functionCategoryID":"LwtYJQvWw97ejLbYWRFJn+S5sVKVXvzDXgYat4Le5zQ="},{"officeID":"NkMDOXBeKbSt2jbZNeVaAJaj2V6LUyN9iHVpq4z9YRc=","firstName":"R6UELs10\/qC+e9Iej1Sfh44H53bC1iez1FX9UoBdmL4=","lastName":"dZh5xGkYre\/Qjv\/d8PnYE+0F+YB\/pACDsOhnbT1vC7I=","userName":"GWl7tJfGtL0VXgL2Jn93KO2j4lTHl7vuEpjS5dvrn0E=","birthdate":"aAYSiKoBVvMZ\/x7zZ3fKW8SLDxSNzSguQ2VtpFqn1\/g=","email":"ZLGkTKft82pwTnRJKFWPkE3BFT4WVPt2Qd1P9Og387A=","functionCategoryID":"b3Wl2KsdFOPDVfsrwg2Y347qGc8PM5Yd8UPS+hY7xSk="}],"IsError":"false","ResponsData":"Success"}
```

My C Sharp

```
public class Datum
            {
                public string OfficeID { get; set; }
                public string firstName { get; set; }
                public string lastName { get; set; }
                public string userName { get; set; }
                public string birthdate { get; set; }
                public string emailEmployee { get; set; }
                public string functionCategory { get; set; }
            }

            public class RootObject
            {
                public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
                public string IsError { get; set; }
                public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
                public string ResponseData { get; set; }
            }

private async void fillDataGridViewAsync()
        {
            // Check cache voor session management
            checkCache.sessionManagement(cacheSettings.getItem("firstName"));

            // Get form data
            string searchBox = txtBxSearch.Text.Trim();

            // Set encrypted data for transport
            string emailSender = CipherForSending.EncryptRJ256(key, iv, email);
            string pwdSender = CipherForSending.EncryptRJ256(key, iv, pwd);
            string search = CipherForSending.EncryptRJ256(key, iv, searchBox);

            // Get connected - Barchart Overview: Visitors
            try
            {
                // request params
                var apiUrl1 = "http://www.test.net/plugin/HumanRelations/getData.php";

                using (var client1 = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var values1 = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "emailSender", emailSender },
                        { "pwdSender", pwdSender },
                        { "search", search }
                    };

                    var content1 = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values1);

                    var response1 = await client1.PostAsync(apiUrl1, content1);

                    var responseString1 = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    //Respons r1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Respons>(responseString1);
                    RootObject r2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseString1);


                    // check response
                    if (r2.ResponseData == "Success")
                    {
                        dgvEmployees.DataSource = r2.data;


                        Cockpit parent = (Cockpit)this.MdiParent;
                        parent.toolStripLabel2.Text = "Loaded succesfully";
                        Notifier.setNotifyMessage(parent.notifyIcon1, "You succesfully loaded your columns!!", "Staff Management Message");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ErrorForm ef = new ErrorForm("Error Message", r2.ErrorMessage);
                        //ef.MdiParent = this;
                        ef.Show();

                        Cockpit parent = (Cockpit)this.MdiParent;
                        parent.toolStripLabel2.Text = "Error";
                        Notifier.setNotifyMessage(parent.notifyIcon1, "Oops, something went wrong!!", "Error Message");
                    }
                }
            }
```

And my php:

```
<?php

include( "library.php" );

try {
    if ( $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] == "POST" ) {
        // Post Request
        //$Email = strip_tags(isset($_POST['Email']) ? $_POST['Email'] : '');
        //$Pwd = strip_tags(isset($_POST['Pwd']) ? $_POST['Pwd'] : '');
        $emailSender = strip_tags( isset( $_POST[ 'emailSender' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'emailSender' ] : '' );
        $pwdSender = strip_tags( isset( $_POST[ 'pwdSender' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'pwdSender' ] : '' );
        $search = strip_tags( isset( $_POST[ 'search' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'search' ] : '' );

        $emailSender2 = CipherData::decryptRJ256( $emailSender );
        $pwdSender2 = CipherData::decryptRJ256( $pwdSender );
        $search2 = CipherData::decryptRJ256( $search );

        // Validate Request
        if ( empty( $pwdSender2 ) || empty( $emailSender2 ) ) {
            throw new Exception( 'Error: Invalid request... Please try again!!' );
        }

        if ( !empty( $pwdSender2 ) && !empty( $emailSender2 ) ) {

            // Set connection
            $conn = Connection::Conn_2();

            // Sanitize data for query
            $emailSender3 = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $emailSender2 );

            // Set Password Hash
            $hash = new VanillaSpecial;
            $hash->Cool_Bananas();
            $hash->Salted_Caramel();
            $pwd3 = $hash->Hash( $pwdSender2 ); // Hashed Password

            //Insert Query of SQL
            $result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Backoffice-employees` WHERE email='$emailSender3' AND password = '$pwd3'" )
            or die( json_encode( array(
                'IsError' => 'true',
                'ErrorMessage' => 'Invalid Request!! Oops, something went wrong. Please try again!!'
            ) ) );

            if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) == 1 ) {

                // Set connection
                $con1 = Connection::Conn_2();

                // Sanitize data for query
                $search3 = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con1, $search2 );

                //Select Query of SQL
                $result1 = mysqli_query( $con1, $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `Backoffice-employees` WHERE userName LIKE '$search3%'" )
                or die( json_encode( array(
                    'IsError' => 'true',
                    'ErrorMessage' => 'Invalid Request!! Oops, something went wrong. Please try again!!'
                ) ) );

            }

            if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result1 ) > 0 ) {

                //$respons = array();
                //$respons['IsError'] = 'false';
                //$respons['ResponseData'] = 'Success';
                $row_array = array();
                $return_arr = array();
                $return_arr['data'] = array();
                $return_arr['IsError'] = 'false';
                $return_arr['ResponseData'] = 'Success';
                $counter = 0;

                //array_push($return_arr, $respons);
                $return_arr['respons'] = $respons;

                // output data of each row
                while ( $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result1 ) ) {

                    $row_array['OfficeID'] = encrypt( $row1[ officeID ] );
                    $row_array['firstName'] = encrypt( $row1[ firstName ] );
                    $row_array['lastName'] = encrypt( $row1[ lastName ] );
                    $row_array['userName'] = encrypt( $row1[ userName ] );
                    $row_array['birthdate'] = encrypt( $row1[ birthdate ] );
                    $row_array['emailEmployee'] = encrypt( $row1[ email ] );
                    $row_array['functionCategory'] = encrypt( $row1[ functionCategoryID ] );

                    //array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
                    $return_arr['data'][$counter] = $row_array;

                    $counter++;

                }   
            }

            exit( json_encode( $return_arr ) );

        }

    } else {
        throw new Exception( 'Error: Invalid access method!!' );
    }

} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    exit( json_encode( array(
        'IsError' => 'true',
        'ErrorMessage' => $e->getMessage()
    ) ) );
}
?>
```

This is the error i get:
System.NullReferenceException: De objectverwijzing is niet op een exemplaar van een object ingesteld.
   bij HBI_Workflow_Management.Items.StaffManagement.d__14.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Jasper\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\HBI Workflow Management UI\HBI Workflow Management\Items\StaffManagement.cs:regel 311

Answer (score 0):

I tried your json string by writing this code and this works fine:

```
namespace testjson
{
    public class Datum
    {
        public string OfficeID { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string birthdate { get; set; }
        public string emailEmployee { get; set; }
        public string functionCategory { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
        public string IsError { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public string ResponseData { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jString= @"{ 'data':[{'officeID':'L4UFJw8GpQPg8iryJlHgeQ8L9wvGaGMozF33HxYrouY=','firstName':'R6UELs10\/qC+e9Iej1Sfh44H53bC1iez1FX9UoBdmL4=','lastName':'dZh5xGkYre\/Qjv\/d8PnYE+0F+YB\/pACDsOhnbT1vC7I=','userName':'oJ9SUemStHW6XGJrRSgQJxBUxHIWKejj3yVjbxiNHH8=','birthdate':'386TvajxJiPRXU4UT5OIqH3jmgSqqmv+n09tqxR9458=','email':'1kuUiACYGwkHseT32NfCbb6QH68Mq09ur5LdBo2SzUhdD6mWQjN9leekZrcZVmzcVCfSA4iEgTIspS3j8naYjg==','functionCategoryID':'79kSmrt7HmEYhqBd+NGd8la3NRVkSaeU+9rx7ri\/jG0='},{'officeID':'Ue86sZNLpM0dZXDBbAw4bgpg36te\/Uym3j\/7c\/RK6So=','firstName':'OK6EiNwnB7Ixb25ua62Us1sCMQ3VlGrjAawtU5pamFk=','lastName':'OK6EiNwnB7Ixb25ua62Us1sCMQ3VlGrjAawtU5pamFk=','userName':'OK6EiNwnB7Ixb25ua62Us1sCMQ3VlGrjAawtU5pamFk=','birthdate':'CgQqdhV3+ZnCSwN6+o9b0kP8i107pgERzWYolkp6dWA=','email':'GHm0Re5AMOEXVjmeuscd5JUAswdDQsvqxzzolEXZ75g=','functionCategoryID':'uIPaVTdcTsORfPMM9kjOdoB5Mf5bZShp2eDrt0bhJA8='},{'officeID':'TQ8MQHfCxpu4XMAYJpDcJ9JIGJ\/oZdZTwirC3O9RoRQ=','firstName':'8PIIK6lsX4q9l39oS+ZIlkpKyhnisTVI3d2qa9Rk7IU=','lastName':'8PIIK6lsX4q9l39oS+ZIlkpKyhnisTVI3d2qa9Rk7IU=','userName':'8PIIK6lsX4q9l39oS+ZIlkpKyhnisTVI3d2qa9Rk7IU=','birthdate':'CgQqdhV3+ZnCSwN6+o9b0kP8i107pgERzWYolkp6dWA=','email':'5EID57UhzVapKSu0hPdlU8++ScgjslS5qiqkNGk5Urk=','functionCategoryID':'uIPaVTdcTsORfPMM9kjOdoB5Mf5bZShp2eDrt0bhJA8='},{'officeID':'87Qn9VDRcho3E9SpkkmN3Voow4xbVRrP6Eg1e9q+LTk=','firstName':'j3PjfbjwOyP\/s2kiXWUrFQT33985hJhymjSgyvVWD88=','lastName':'j3PjfbjwOyP\/s2kiXWUrFQT33985hJhymjSgyvVWD88=','userName':'j3PjfbjwOyP\/s2kiXWUrFQT33985hJhymjSgyvVWD88=','birthdate':'aAYSiKoBVvMZ\/x7zZ3fKW8SLDxSNzSguQ2VtpFqn1\/g=','email':'cnHQfIfyGbaSGW9aVPCPkpZ0fxtN2vH8\/Rmhfa61GpU=','functionCategoryID':'uIPaVTdcTsORfPMM9kjOdoB5Mf5bZShp2eDrt0bhJA8='},{'officeID':'fJrhmHvZkTb909xEuy9GBDFTzwmBqOAzJMSdv\/z2NeY=','firstName':'R6UELs10\/qC+e9Iej1Sfh44H53bC1iez1FX9UoBdmL4=','lastName':'dZh5xGkYre\/Qjv\/d8PnYE+0F+YB\/pACDsOhnbT1vC7I=','userName':'u2Q+5N0qfGXguAAXPrjfg27bKcsfn9kmuFirw3D+ESE=','birthdate':'aAYSiKoBVvMZ\/x7zZ3fKW8SLDxSNzSguQ2VtpFqn1\/g=','email':'acpGLJU7viDD8bvDP6cehUtKu4jsu0S7NocWzWI5HsU=','functionCategoryID':'uIPaVTdcTsORfPMM9kjOdoB5Mf5bZShp2eDrt0bhJA8='},{'officeID':'+F8IDemrdYxhfhZRffkcfpC8XRS13jl1zee8jCYZo+k=','firstName':'R6UELs10\/qC+e9Iej1Sfh44H53bC1iez1FX9UoBdmL4=','lastName':'dZh5xGkYre\/Qjv\/d8PnYE+0F+YB\/pACDsOhnbT1vC7I=','userName':'ZaBSv\/5EzxsxaPLVex1m3s0FZ5AAsPHejn1N7qe5lHo=','birthdate':'aAYSiKoBVvMZ\/x7zZ3fKW8SLDxSNzSguQ2VtpFqn1\/g=','email':'dluwI6UQb8M\/eRyaw0YHfX2+kfK2Q1HebrBoQP9Uths=','functionCategoryID':'LwtYJQvWw97ejLbYWRFJn+S5sVKVXvzDXgYat4Le5zQ='},{'officeID':'7jqdChVFIQt5cdXznM5Qmv1EOqgfpi580OHek1L2FVA=','firstName':'R6UELs10\/qC+e9Iej1Sfh44H53bC1iez1FX9UoBdmL4=','lastName':'dZh5xGkYre\/Qjv\/d8PnYE+0F+YB\/pACDsOhnbT1vC7I=','userName':'iShpHaczQ4RtkHVvXmv3nRv8m59qppApLQ99Civ1QlU=','birthdate':'aAYSiKoBVvMZ\/x7zZ3fKW8SLDxSNzSguQ2VtpFqn1\/g=','email':'pq9yUcG+VK5xlHpemKm9B7sE7PxlCdCkFpzhIy\/8k8g=','functionCategoryID':'LwtYJQvWw97ejLbYWRFJn+S5sVKVXvzDXgYat4Le5zQ='},{'officeID':'NkMDOXBeKbSt2jbZNeVaAJaj2V6LUyN9iHVpq4z9YRc=','firstName':'R6UELs10\/qC+e9Iej1Sfh44H53bC1iez1FX9UoBdmL4=','lastName':'dZh5xGkYre\/Qjv\/d8PnYE+0F+YB\/pACDsOhnbT1vC7I=','userName':'GWl7tJfGtL0VXgL2Jn93KO2j4lTHl7vuEpjS5dvrn0E=','birthdate':'aAYSiKoBVvMZ\/x7zZ3fKW8SLDxSNzSguQ2VtpFqn1\/g=','email':'ZLGkTKft82pwTnRJKFWPkE3BFT4WVPt2Qd1P9Og387A=','functionCategoryID':'b3Wl2KsdFOPDVfsrwg2Y347qGc8PM5Yd8UPS+hY7xSk='}],'IsError':'false','ResponsData':'Success'}";
           var yourObject =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jString);
        }
```

}
I used Newtonsoft library, as it is suggested by microsoft, I have no idea about the library that you used.
Another thing that may cause the issue was double quotations that you used for your json, if I wanted to keep them I should add backslash before them that caused another issue with the slashed in the code, so I just changed them to single quotation and then your json string is valid and works fine.

Comment: Thanx for your answer Mehrdad. If you could give me the PHP script to do that it would be great. I tried string replace with my JSON encode but doesn't work.

Comment: I changed my double quotations into single ones (exit( str_replace('"', "'",json_encode( $return_arr )) );) of my PHP but still no luck. Still the same error when I check my responsdata.

Comment: Do you have your php api hosted somewhere on the web? if so give me the address to check your output

Comment: No need to, it works. You're awesome man! Figured out the bug with your help and it runs smoothly now.